# Cannot delete relationship record if one of the navigation properties is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have the following models, `Program` and `Group`, and a `ProgramGroup` junction table relationship entity:

```
public class Program
{
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentProgramId { get; set; }
    public Program ParentProgram { get; set; }
    public IList<ProgramGroup> ProgramGroups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProgramGroup
{
    public int ProgramGroupId { get; set; }
    public int ProgramId { get; set; }
    public Program Program { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public string Pin { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I actually have to create a `ProgramGroup` class because the relationship has behavior (the `Pin` property).

The following code is supposed to severe a relationship between a `Program` and `Group` by deleting a `ProgramGroup`.

```
public void Delete(ProgramGroup programGroup)
{
    context.ProgramGroups.Remove(programGroup);
}
```

When a program is updated in my application's interface and a relationship between program and group removed, I retrieve the original program, determine if any `ProgramGroup`s that were removed, and then call the `Delete` method above.  The delete is failing.

As I've been debugging, I've noticed that the `Program` navigation property of the `ProgramGroup` to be deleted is null while the `Group` navigation property is not null.  It is null because when I retrieve the original program, I null out the `Program` property on all of the program's `ProgramGroup`s.  I had to do this because I was getting a self-referencing loop error.  When I remove the line of code that nulls out the `Program` property of all `ProgramGroups`, the `Program` property on the `ProgramGroup` to be deleted is not null and the delete is executed successfully.

Why is EF choking on the delete of a relationship entity when one of the navigation properties is null.

Comment: Did you also try removing the `ProgramGroup` object from the `ProgramGroups` property of the `Program` object?

Comment: @howcheng: When are you suggesting to do that?

Comment: Just a wild guess, is it possible it is happening because your `programGroup` object is `Dettached`, which can be checked as `dbcontext.Entry(programGroup).State`. Attaching the entity before delete might help. Again this is just a wild guess :)

Comment: @im1dermike I would do it before removing the ProgramGroup from the context. Not sure if that will actually accomplish anything, though.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the issue is caused by having to null out the `Program` property of my ProgramGroups.  This was something I was doing to avoid a self-referencing loop exception as I converted from my domain entity to my view model which is actually caused by AutoMapper.  EF correctly populates the navigation properties on my objects and AutoMapper was automatically mapping things infinitely:

```
Program > ProgramGroup > Program > ProgramGroup > Program > ProgramGroup ...
```

This is why I had to null out `Program`.  What was happening was that when I went to delete a ProgramGroup, EF wasn't able to match it with an existing ProgramGroup because the Program property was null and it was causing problems.

Unfortunately, I was focused on EF being the cause of the problem, not AutoMapper.  I simply had to change my AutoMapper config from:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProgramGroup, ProgramGroupViewModel>();
```

to:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProgramGroup, ProgramGroupViewModel>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Program, x => x.MapFrom(v => (Program)null));
```